# iOS 11 - <a href="tel:1-427-555-05-05"> links only work with long tap on iPhone, single tap doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

Hello StackOverflow community

I am building iOS 11 Swift `WKWebView` app, currently it is browsing an https remote web site

I've made a phone call page, with html code like

```
<a href="tel:78122931709">+7 (812) 293-17-09</a>
<a href="tel:78122931709">Make a phone call</a>
```

But for some reasons, on the iPhone SE under iOS 11.2.6 the tel links are only opened by long tap. For single tap the app does nothing.

On iPad Air 2 under iOS 11.2.6 single tap works, options appear after single tap instantly, not after long tap.

What I want to do is make iPhone app with `WKWebView` open prompt to call on single tap, not after long tap and choosing first option. Is there any way to do it?

[image: iphone app screenshot 1] [image: iphone app screenshot 2 - after longtap]

[image: iphone app screenshot 3 - choosing first option to call phone number finally the prompt to call appears]

[image: ipad app screenshot 1]

[image: ipad app screenshot 2 singletap works and options appear instantly, without long tap link]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch from using WKWebView to deprecated UIWebView

All telephone phone links work fine on iPhone on UIWebView